# How do I mock react-native-ibeacon in jest

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, jestjs

I am trying to mock react-native-ibeacon (a native module, I just want to test how it is called, including all functions in the Beacons object below).

Here is a code snippet that leaves Beacons undefined:

```
var React = require('react-native');
var Beacons = require('react-native-ibeacon');
jest.mock('react-native-ibeacon');

describe('beaconView', () => {

  console.log('Beacons', Beacons);

  Beacons.requestWhenInUseAuthorization();

  it('test pass', () => {
    expect(1).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

It fails when I try and call the requestWhenInUseAuthorization method.

What am I missing?

Comment: I think the problem is that Beacons depends on a bridge between javascript and iOS that doesn't exist when I run with jest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to provide a good mock using the second argument to `jest.mock`.

Example:

```
jest.mock('my-module', () => ({
    myFn: jest.fn();
}));
```

and then you can do:

```
const myModule = require('my-module');

myModule.myFn() // calling the mock function.
```

you need to figure out what features your external native module has and then create a mock that can behave similarly.

Comment: Excellent, I will head off in that direction. Thank you!